# How to add a PageModel to a Razor component?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor

I am looking through some code and someone made a Razor component with a separate PageModel.

How can I create something like this?

Razor component with its PageModel:

[image]

In folder:

[image]

I don't understand how to make a Razor component in two parts like this.
Can someone explain how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a Razor component
2. Create the class item with the same name as the Razor component.
   The files will automatically nest (like Razor Pages). There is a button in Solution Explorer, which allows you to disable automatic nesting.
3. Rename the .cs (class item) to public partial class
4. You can delete the `@{}` from the component

There is also a second method in which the HTML page inherits the class. Here is a good YouTube video on that:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4CeEFuY_ieg

Comment: This doesn't add a PageModel -- the partial class is not derived from `PageModel` . It just moves the C# code to another file.