# How to make Razor pages with Page Model use _Host and _Layout?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, blazor

In a Blazor project (.NET 6.0 or 7.0, same problem happens in both) in VS2022 Pro, I am trying to add a page with Page Model.

I have previously used Razor Pages without page model, which works OK but [according to guides](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/pagemodel), using a separate Page Model is good for maintainability. Also, the feature "Pages > Add > Razor Page > Razor Pages using Entity Framework (CRUD)" , which I would like to use, generates pages with Page Model.

Using Pages > Add New Item > "Razor Page - Empty" (caption "A razor page with a page model"), it adds new files `Foo.cshtml` and `Foo.cshtml.cs` with the page and the model in separate files.  The `Foo.cshtml` starts with a directive `@page` with no argument.

So far so good, however navigating to `/Foo` (in the browser), it just renders the HTML in `Foo.cshtml` as-is , it is not part of the `_Layout`,  and tag helpers in the EF+CRUD demo aren't working because the `@addTagHelper` directive is in `_Host.cshtml` which isn't being loaded either for this page.

What do I have to do to load the `_Host` and `_Layout` for pages with a page model?

For Razor Pages without Page Model (i.e. `.razor` file) there isn't any directive to specify `_Host`, it seems to just "magically" use `_Host` (I figure this comes from `app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host")` in Program.cs). But the pages with Page Model don't do that.

To reproduce this, start a new Blazor App (this makes an app that fetches the weather report) and the Pages > Add New Item > Razor Page - Empty, and try to navigate to the new page using browser address bar.

---

The question [How to add PageModel to Razor component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67951676/how-to-add-pagemodel-to-razor-component) seems related but the solution there isn't viable since it does not involve `PageModel`. The wizard "Pages > Add > Razor Page > Razor Pages using Entity Framework (CRUD)" generates code inside the model like `return Page();` and `return RedirectToPage("./Index");` which won't compile if we are not in a Model derived from `PageModel`.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it now -- the guides recommending a separate Page Model are out of date, and come from a time before Blazor.  Blazor pages each have a Page Model of their own, with the `@code` section performing a similar function to the body of the Page Model class.

The solution on [How to add PageModel to Razor component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67951676/how-to-add-pagemodel-to-razor-component) question is just using 2 source files to do exactly the same thing as you would otherwise do in 1 source file with a Blazor component, it doesn't expose any additional functionality.

The menu option `Pages > Add New Item > Razor Page - Empty` is not appropriate to use in a Blazor project now.